# Redis in Docker across multiple cluster

Tags: redis, dockerfile, redis-cluster

I am new to Redis.

I want to deploy redis cache across multiple clusters in a container. Is there a way to achieve the same?

Question -
1. How discovery will happen between redis nodes across clusters.
2. If someone tried and have a simple dockerfile, please share the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use redis sentinel for distributed caching https://redis.io/topics/sentinel  or redis cluster if you want to do sharding, to make Docker compatible with Redis Cluster you need to use the host networking mode of Docker. https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to setup master-master redis or master-slave(fallback) cache system.

Comment: Thanks @MrFox. I want to do data sharding using redis cluster across few vms on two static cluster.

Comment: There are different ways you can do this, depends on your requirements 

Client side partitioning  -  means you need to implement client which handles where to write and read from
, Proxy assisted partitioning - where you can use proxy layers like (https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy, https://github.com/Netflix/dynomite) which make sure to forward requests to the right Redis instance according to the configured partitioning schema

Comment: Query routing :  you can send your query to a random instance, and the instance will make sure to forward your query to the right node, redis cluster implements an hybrid form of query routing

I suggest you to read this https://redis.io/topics/partitioning and highly recommend netflix dynomite if you want to use proxy based approach.